# Is it possible to install the replication when sql server is running?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, replication

I need to add replication feature on production server. 
Is it possible to install the replication when sql server 2008 R2 is running (any issues with CRUD operation or etc)?
Can it be any issues with it ?

Comment: If SQL Server isn't running, how are you expected to configure the Publisher server?

Comment: question is related to any issues what could be happen on DB what is using right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install Replication components without interrupting normal service.  The only hard requirement is after installing Replication components, you must restart the SQL Server Agent for it to recognize the replication agent subsystems.